# Using python mySQL pooling to get and close pooled connections from different functions in Database Class

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, persistent, pooling

I have a Python database file, with MySQL Pooling setup like below

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error
from mysql.connector.connection import MySQLConnection
from mysql.connector import pooling


import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
from contextlib import closing

#Outside of any function :
connection_pool = mysql.connector.pooling.MySQLConnectionPool(pool_name="database_pool",
                                                           pool_size=25,
                                                           pool_reset_session=True,
                                                           host='XXXXX',
                                                           database='XXXXX',
                                                           user='XXXXX',
                                                           password='XXXX')
```

In order to get a pooled connection I use the blow function located within the same file

```
def getDBConnection():
  try:
      connection_obj = connection_pool.get_connection()
      cursor = connection_obj.cursor()
      return connection_obj, cursor
  except Error as e:
     print(f"Error while connecting to MySQL using Connection pool : {e}")
```

Now lets say I want to preform a simple select function using a pooled connection (still within the same database file) - and then return the connection :

```
def dbGetDataHeadersForRunMenuBySubSet(strSubset):
    connection_object, cursor = getDBConnection() 
    if connection_object.is_connected(): 
        query = 'SELECT * FROM someTable'
        cursor.execute(query)
           
        #Now close the connection
        closeDBConnection(connection_object, cursor)
```

code to attempt to close the Pool :

```
def closeDBConnection(connection_obj,cursor):
    if connection_obj.is_connected():
        connection_obj.close()
        cursor.close()
```

However after 25 runs I get the error back saying

```
Error while connecting to MySQL using Connection pool : Failed getting connection; pool exhausted
```

Using the debugger I can see that the closeDBConnection is been run , and that it appears to hit every step with no errors.

So my question is :
Why am I running out of pools if I am closing them each time ?

All in all, I am actually looking to make a persistent connection , but in Python I cant find any realy examples on persistence , and all the examples I have looked at seem to point towards pooling. I am new (ish) to Python - so I have no issues here syaing that I know I have made a mistake somewhere.

Having played with this further :
adding "connection_object.close()" at the end of each individual function will free the connection_pool e.g

```
def dbGetDataHeadersForRunMenuBySubSet(strSubset):
    connection_object, cursor = getDBConnection() 
    if connection_object.is_connected(): 
        query = 'SELECT * FROM someTable'
        cursor.execute(query)
           
        #Now close the connection
        #closeDBConnection(connection_object, cursor) <--- Not working for me
        connection_object.close() <---- This WILL work instead. –
```

But the DB stuff is just so slow in comparrision to Excel mySQL Connecter (Excel is almost 3 times faster doing the same thing. I think this is because its easy to get a persistent connection in EXCEL - something which I cant do in python (I am new remember ;-) )

Comment: You shouldn't need to control the connection pool yourself - does it work up a level if you just use connections and dispose of them as soon as the immediate query is done?

Comment: I have called the connection from a different class - e.g called a function to create a connection string from a completly different class , and then just passed the param around via different functions to prevent having to reconnect. Other than that , I am not sure what you mean by  "does it work up a level"

Comment: Does this answer: [using one database connection across multiple functions in python](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/291705/175972) help?

Comment: Thanks mate. I tried this pooling method (I am actually using it) BUT I need to call the functions from many different classes. I actually just got the connection once and "carried" it around from method to method.

I would have hoped there was just some global connection variable I could use. I dont actually need many connections at once (in fact everything is in sequence) so just trying to keep the DB Connection open is all I need. Thanks for the help @AndrewMorton